# Ionic - Remove object from local storage

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I'm currently working with local storage for my Ionic app. I can add and get data from local storage, but when I try to delete a specific object, everything in my DB gets removed. And when I try to add a new object in my (now empty) DB I get the error message:
"Runtime error - Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

The apps user scenario is that a user adds a favorite tv show to a favorites list, and from there be able to unfavorite if wanted to.

Here's my code in my service which holds the functions for the localstorage:

```
export class FavoritesService{

  constructor(private storage: Storage){}
  public favoritesSeries: any = [];

  addSeriesToFavorites(serie: any)
  {
    this.favoritesSeries.push(serie);
    console.log('Add to');
    console.log(this.favoritesSeries);
    this.storage.set('FavSerie',this.favoritesSeries);
  }

  getFavoriteSeries(){

      this.favoritesSeries = [];

      this.storage.get('FavSerie').then((val) => {
        console.log(val);
        if (val){
          this.favoritesSeries = val;
        }});
  }

  removeFavoriteSeries(){
    this.storage.remove('FavSerie').then((val)=>{
      this.favoritesSeries = val
      console.log('serie is removed');
    });
  }

  saveChanges(favoriteSeries: any) {
    this.favoritesSeries = favoriteSeries;
    this.storage.set('favoriteSeries', this.favoritesSeries);
  }
}
```

My favorites page:

```
export class Favorites {

  series: {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public seriesService: SeriesService,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              public favoritesService: FavoritesService) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    //presents the favorite series
    this.series = this.favoritesService.favoritesSeries;
    console.log(this.favoritesService.favoritesSeries);
    console.log(this.series);
  }

  onRemoveFromFavorites(FavSerie: any){
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Remove From Favorites',
      subTitle: 'Are you sure?',
      message: 'Are you sure you want to remove from favorites?',
      buttons: [

        {
          text: 'Yes',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('OK');
            console.log(FavSerie);
            this.favoritesService.removeFavoriteSeries();
            console.log('efter service addToFavorite');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'No',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your data like this:

- Edit the `favoritesSeries`
- Save `favoritesSeries` to storage as `FavSerie`

This is fine, but your method `removeFavoriteSeries` works like like this:

- Remove `FavSerie` (which is your array of series) from DB
- Set the `favoritesSeries` to whatever is resolved by the promise that is returned form `storage.remove`

To fix your code you can edit your `removeFavoriteSeries` to this:

```
removeFavoriteSeries(serie: any){
    this.favoritesSeries = this.favoritesSeries.filter(s => s !== serie);
    this.saveChanges(this.favoritesSeries);
}
```

What this does is:

- Edits the `favoritesSeries` list that contains all the series
- Saves the (now changed) `favoritesSeries` to the storage

This is in line with the rest of your code that edits the list of series.

Now when you call the  `removeFavoriteSeries` method and give it the `serie` that you want removed it will remove it.

On a side note you should really consider setting a fixed type for your serie object. You could have seen this error in compile time if the `favoritesSeries` was an array of fixed types.

**Edit:**

Now you should edit the `onRemoveFromFavorites` in your `Favorites` class:

Instead of `this.favoritesService.removeFavoriteSeries();` it should be `this.favoritesService.removeFavoriteSeries(FavSerie);`.

With this you are passing to your `FavoritesService` the serie you want to remove.

Also, you should edit your `addSeriesToFavorites` like this:

```
addSeriesToFavorites(serie: any)
{
    this.favoritesSeries.push(serie);
    console.log('Add to');
    console.log(this.favoritesSeries);
    this.saveChanges(this.favoritesSeries); // <- use the saving method
```

}

Comment: This almost worked! When I press "Unfavorite" it saves a new array of favoriteSeries in my DB. But I still see all my series in the list if I refresh the page in the browser..

Also, my favorites.ts file doesn't work the way it shows up in my original post. The method to remove series is red and says: "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target". Why shouldn't i send in my FavSerie array?

Comment: You should edit the `onRemoveFromFavorites`. I added the example of use in the answer.

Comment: One step closer! It still removes everything in my list, even if I just press "unfavorite" on one serie. But atleast my problem with adding a new serie when I've removed to series is solved, I don't get the same error anymore. This how my DB looks like now: https://imgur.com/a/7N1YP

Comment: Glad to hear I answered your question. The problems you describe now seem to be a subject for a new question.

Comment: I took another look at the code and edited my answer so the code uses one method to save and add. With this you should stop having 2 entries in your db. Care to give any feedback?